# How to use my @EnvironmentObject in AppDelegate in SwiftUi (iOS 15 / Xcode 13.2.1)?

Tags: ios, swiftui, appdelegate, environmentobject

I have a class :

```swift
class AppInfos_M: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentUser: User_M = User_M()
    @Published var userTo: User_M = User_M()
}
```

I declare it in `main` and pass in to my view with `environmentObject`:

```swift
...

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
...

    @StateObject var appInfos_M = AppInfos_M()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            LaunchScreen_V()
                .environmentObject(appInfos_M)
...
 
        }
    }
}
```

The class works very good in my app. Now I need to modify it from `AppDelegate`, because I need to get `appInfos_M.userTo.id` when I get a notification. I tried several things, but none works. How can I access it?

In all my views where I need it, I declare this way and it works fine, but not in `AppDelegate`, why?:

```swift
 @EnvironmentObject var appInfos_M: AppInfos_M
```

Here is one of the tests I tried that did not work:

```swift
...

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate { ... }

...

@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

...

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

@EnvironmentObject var appInfos_M: AppInfos_M

 let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

appInfos_M.userTo.id = "just for testing here" // <- i get this error : Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type AppInfos_M found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for AppInfos_M may be missing as an ancestor of this view.

...
```

*Note that 3 small dots `...` replace any code that is useless here.*

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64484944/12299030?

Comment: You can't access the environment from your app delegate; the environment is only available from the view hierarchy.  You can simply create a property in your app delegate adapter and assign your value to it

Answer (score 5):

You can always store `AppInfos_M` in your `AppDelegate` Like this

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var appInfos = AppInfos_M()
    (...)
}
```

You can then use it as EnvironmentObject as:

```
...
@main
struct TestApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
...
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            LaunchScreen_V()
                .environmentObject(appDelegate.appInfos)
...
 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. It worked for me w/out having to use a singleton as many of the other posts did.

Comment: I was about to refactor my code to use a singleton, until I found this! Perfect solution! Why some basic stuff has to be so complicated or overlooked in SwiftUI?

Comment: Happy to help :-) I definitely struggled with these things when I started doing iOS development in SwifUI without prior UIKit knowledge